# Wordpress columns how to change?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am new to theming with Wordpress.

I have a theme layout with one column at the right side of the website.

Now on my homepage and one other page I don't want to have a column at all.
How can I do this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could get better help at wordpress.stackexchange.com but

to answer your question..

if you do not want the column on the right on your page and homepage.

i'm assuming you are trying to remove a sidebar. is that right?

go to your `index.php` page and `page.php` file and 
try to remove `<?php get_sidebar(); ?>` and you should probably get rid of any `divs` holding the sidebar.

my 2 cents.

Comment: Thanks for the sitelink. The problem is that i do not want to remove it on all pages. Just on 2 pages. Any idea or should i go to wordpress.stackexchange.com?

Comment: ok do you have the id of the page that you do not want it to appear on? if so you could do `<?php if(!is_page(put-here-id-of-page)){ ?> <?php get_sidebar(); ?> <?php } ?>` this should work just make sure to put your id inside. let me know..